# Does dexguard provide encryption of any URLs used in the code

Tags: android, dexguard

I want to encrypt my android application so that it is hard to be decompiled or reverse engineered. For this I have come across dexguard. I checked from its fact-sheet that it offer multiple level of encryption and obfuscation. So I want to know whether it will also encrypt any web calls as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DexGuard you can even encrypt whole Java class. Due to the performance reason, it is better to encrypt the minimal set of classes.

Put all your URLs in a single Java class and encrypt the class. Also, you can obfuscate all html files under asset folder using DexGuard.

Comment: Yes it does encrypts/obfuscates the string URL's and now after applying obfuscation layers we are able to put some base level security to the code.

Answer (score 0):

Dexguard does string encryption but I use proguard and I encrypt some URL by my self.

I get the encryption key doing XOR between the characters of two apparently innocent strings